# visual studio c# split string into variables

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, split, arduino

im hopeing somone can help me, ive created a interface using the visual studio IDE,which is also connected to an arduino. i had a issue with reading the data, however it has been solved. the data sent from the arduino looks like this 1,2,3, the issue i am having is that every time i try to split the string, into seprate variables it doesnt seem to work. i will post the code for both parts below. if anyone could help me figure this out would be great

visual studio :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SerialPort myport;

        int irisvalue;

        string myString;
        String s;

        //string[] words;

        String readString;

        String firstValue;
        String secondValue;
        String thirdValue;

        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
            //Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
            connectbtn.Text = "Connect";
            disconnect.Text = "Disconnect";
            this.connectbtn.Click += new EventHandler(connectbtn_Click);
            this.disconnect.Click += new EventHandler(disconnect_Click);
            this.iris1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.iris1_MouseDown);
            this.iris1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.iris1_MouseUp);
            this.iris2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.iris2_MouseDown);
            this.iris2.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.iris2_MouseUp);
            this.focus1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.focus1_MouseDown);
            this.focus1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.focus1_MouseUp);
            this.focus2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.focus2_MouseDown);
            this.focus2.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.focus2_MouseUp);

        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


         void connect()
        {

            myport = new SerialPort();
            myport.BaudRate = 9600;
            myport.PortName = "COM3";
            myport.Open();

        }

        void read()
        {


            myport.DataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
                    s = myport.ReadLine();

            };

        }

        void discon()
        {


            myport.Close();

        }

        private void disconnect_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            discon();
            if (myport.IsOpen)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                connectbtn.Text = "Connect";
                disconnect.BackColor = default(Color);
                connectbtn.BackColor = default(Color);
            }
            }

            private void connectbtn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            connect();

            if (myport.IsOpen)
            {

                connectbtn.Text = "Connected";
                connectbtn.BackColor = Color.Green;
                //Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
                Form1_Load();
                disconnect.BackColor = Color.Red;
                disconnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                read();
                //s = myport.ReadLine();





            }
            else
            {
                connectbtn.Text = "Error";
                connectbtn.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }


        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void iris1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello");

            irisvalue = 1;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();

        }

        private void iris1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            irisvalue = 0;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();
        }



        private void iris2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            irisvalue = 2;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();

        }


        private void iris2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            irisvalue = 0;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();

        }

        private void focus1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            irisvalue = 3;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();

        }


        private void focus1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            irisvalue = 0;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();


        }

        private void focus2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            irisvalue = 4;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();

        }

        private void focus2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            irisvalue = 0;
            myString = irisvalue.ToString();
            Form1_Load();
        }



        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public void Form1_Load()
            {





            readString += s;


            if (readString.Length > 0)
            {

                int commaIndex = readString.IndexOf(',');
                int secondCommaIndex = readString.IndexOf(',', commaIndex + 1);

                firstValue = readString.Substring(0, commaIndex);
                secondValue = readString.Substring(commaIndex + 1, secondCommaIndex);
                thirdValue = readString.Substring(secondCommaIndex + 1); // To the end of the string

                //int x = Int32.Parse(firstValue);
                //int y = Int32.Parse(secondValue);
               // int z = thirdValue.toInt();



                Console.WriteLine(firstValue);
                Console.WriteLine(secondValue);
                Console.WriteLine(thirdValue);
            }


            myport.WriteLine(myString);




        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    }

}
```

Arduino :

```
String readString;

int INA = 11;
int INB = 9;
int INC = 7;
int IND = 5;

int ledpin = 3;

int inPin = 14;
int inPin2 = 15;

int reading; 
int reading2; 
int nu;

const String com = ",";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(INA, OUTPUT);
pinMode(INB, OUTPUT);
pinMode(INC, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IND, OUTPUT);

pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);

pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
pinMode(inPin2, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

 reading = analogRead(inPin);
reading2 = analogRead(inPin2);

while(Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
    readString += c; //makes the string readString

    delay(5);  //slow looping to allow buffer to fill with next character
}


if (readString.length() >0) {
    //Serial.println(readString);  //so you can see the captured string 
   //int n = readString.toInt();  //convert readString into a number

   int commaIndex = readString.indexOf(',');
   int secondCommaIndex = readString.indexOf(',', commaIndex+1);

String firstValue = readString.substring(0, commaIndex);
String secondValue = readString.substring(commaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
String thirdValue = readString.substring(secondCommaIndex+1); // To the end of the string

int x = firstValue.toInt();
int y = secondValue.toInt();
int z = thirdValue.toInt();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (x == 1){

digitalWrite(INA, HIGH);
digitalWrite(INB, LOW);
digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
digitalWrite(IND, LOW);

}

else if (x == 2){


digitalWrite(INA, LOW);
digitalWrite(INB, HIGH);
digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
digitalWrite(IND, LOW);

}

else if (x == 3){


digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
digitalWrite(IND, LOW);
digitalWrite(INA, LOW);
digitalWrite(INB, LOW);

}

else if (x == 4){


digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
digitalWrite(IND, HIGH);
digitalWrite(INA, LOW);
digitalWrite(INB, LOW);

}


else{

digitalWrite(INA, LOW);
digitalWrite(INB, LOW);
digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
digitalWrite(IND, LOW);


}

Serial.println(1 + com + 2 + com + 3);
//Serial.print(", ");
//Serial.print(reading);
//Serial.print(", ");
//Serial.print(reading2);
//Serial.println(", ");


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}



readString=""; //empty for next input


}
```

Comment: Way too much code for the problem you ask about. Make a minimal, complete example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
            int commaIndex = readString.IndexOf(',');
            int secondCommaIndex = readString.IndexOf(',', commaIndex + 1);

            firstValue = readString.Substring(0, commaIndex);
            secondValue = readString.Substring(commaIndex + 1, secondCommaIndex);
            thirdValue = readString.Substring(secondCommaIndex + 1); // To the end of the string
```

with this:

```
            string[] values = readString.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            firstValue = values[0];
            secondValue = values[1];
            thirdValue = values[2];
```

Hope it helps.

PS - this assumes you always have three values, as you did in your code.

PPS - this will only work in your C# code. My understanding is that you are sending the string from Arduino to winforms - and splitting is only necessary in the winforms app.

Comment: He's using Arduino, so there is no Split function. I thought the same thing at first as well.

Comment: The first bit of code seems to be a legitimate windows forms app - don't see how string.split wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh, now I noticed he has the same code on the Arduino side, too. Thanks - will try to clear it up.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please don't put all of your code, rather, only the part your question is pertaining to.

[See this original post for separating the string based on the separator and passing an index to get the value.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1237)

```
String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
int found = 0;
int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
    if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
        found++;
        strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
        strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
}
return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```

You can then call the function passing in your `readString` variable along with the index of which variable you want:

```
String firstValue = getValue(readString,',',0);
String secondValue = getValue(readString,',',1);
String thirdValue = getValue(readString,',',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Split method available in String (C#). As in:

```
     string[] myVars = readString.Split(",");
     if (myVars.Length > 2)
     {
         firstValue = myVars[0];
         secondValue = myVars[1];
         thirdValue = myVars[2];
    }
```

Launch in debug mode and check the contents of readString.